# IPP request CUPS server C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, cups

I have a backend made with C# and .NET 6, and my goal is to send labels to a ZD420 printer that is in a CUPS server.

Based on my research I found that I should use IPP to send requests to the CUPS server to send my files, track the queues, cancel the printing, etc. What I do not understand is how to send those IPP requests and if there is a library or something to help me with that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.